# Uncaught ReferenceError: swal : Sweetalert2 with laravel project is not working

Tags: javascript, laravel, sweetalert2

I am using sweetalert 2 with laravel project, it works fine when I am using *CDN* link, but it does not work after installation through `npm install --save sweetalert2` and gives the following error.

```
posts:1441 Uncaught ReferenceError: swal is not defined
at posts:1441:23
```

(anonymous) @ posts:1441

my code:

**1: with cdn**

```
   <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10"></script>
<script>
    const Toast = swal.mixin({
        toast: true,
        position: 'top-right',
        showConfirmButton: false,
        showCloseButton: true,
        timer: 5000,
        timerProgressBar: true,
        didOpen: (toast) => {
            toast.addEventListener('mouseenter', Swal.stopTimer)
            toast.addEventListener('mouseleave', Swal.resumeTimer)
        }
    });

    window.addEventListener('alert', ({
        detail: {
            type,
            message
        }
    }) => {
        Toast.fire({
            icon: type,
            title: message
        })
    })
</script>
```

this works fine, but i dont want to use cdn.

**2: through npm:**

**steps**

*First*

```
npm install --save sweetalert2
```

*Second* in *app.js*

```
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
```

*Third*

```
npm run dev
```

but it does not work.

how can we solve the problem?

Comment: All of the examples I can see in the [docs](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) use `Swal` and not `swal` (you're also importing `Swal` not `swal`). Have you tried using `Swal`?

Comment: Yes i did, it is not working

Comment: Are you sure?  The error you've pasted plainly shows `swal`, lower-case.  Have you really replaced all lower-case cases, everywhere in your code?

Comment: Yeah, I did. Capital case is not working too.